# Captcha no funciona sin GD library

Tags: wordpress, xampp

Estoy instalando un plugin en Wordpress que usa un CAPTCHA pero al mostrarlo me muestra un error:
Error! CAPTCHA requires the GD library activated in your PHP configuration.
Investigando sobre esto he leido que debo consultar si tengo dicha libreria GD instalada pero al ejecutar un phpinfo() veo que dicha libreria no esta entre las que me aparecen. Para solucionar esto he leido que bastaría (en windows) habilitar en php.ini la extension extension=php_gd2.dll pero veo que dicha extension no aparece en mi php.ini. Lo he añadido de todos modos por si pudiera funcionar pero no da ningún resultado. No sé mucho sobre esto pero me dá la impresión que no este siquiera instalada dicha libreria y que tenga que hacerlo manualmente. ¿Alguién podría decirme como hacerlo?
Nota: estoy utilizando como servidor un XAMPP v.3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Encontré como activar la libreria GD en XAMPP. Tan solo hay que ir a php.ini y activar la linea: "extension=gd" . Con eso ya se muestra correctamente el CAPTCHA.